# Windows get Unix like path from cygwin root

Tags: c, winapi, filesystems, cygwin

I want to get the path to my current directory ( `pwd` ) in unix-style from cygwin root, but when I use `GetCurrentDirectory` it prints the path from C in windows path style.

What other function does the windows api has in order to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the Cygwin version of [getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd). Windows API functions like `GetCurrentDirectory` work with Windows paths, not Cygwin paths.